# Require minimum number of data points before plotting a point in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Can I cause Tableau to require a certain number of underlying data points before plotting a point on the graph?

For example, here's a graph showing average moods over the course of the day on Tuesdays:

[image: Tableau line graph]

There's nothing uniquely awful about midnight on Tuesdays, it's just that there's only one data point for that particular time, and it's an outlier. Is it possible to have the graph show midnight as missing unless there are more than (for example) three different records from midnight being averaged together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an aggregate calculated field, called say avg_mood as:

```
if count(Mood) >= 3 then avg(Mood) end
```

Since the aggregation is hard coded into the calculation, Tableau will display AGG(avg_mood) for the field on any shelves you use it on, rather than letting you toggle the aggregation outside the formula as it will for other measures.

Note, there is no else branch, so the calculation will evaluate to null if there are less than three non-null Moods in a partition of data rows (based on the dimensions)

You can control how null values are displayed in a line chart. On the format pane, select the field in question from the pull down menu by the word Fields at the top right of the format pane, then select the Pane tab, then at the bottom of the format pane, adjust the Mark settings in the Special value section.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I also discovered that for initial exploration it can be useful to add count to the Size property, which lets you see where you have scant data and view the number of measurements in a point by hovering over it.